# Settting up a SSMS Linked Server to DB2

Tags: sql-server-2008, db2, ssms

I have a local SQL Server instance on which I created a Linked Server connection to a DB2 database named "DB2OurDatabase."  In creating the Linked Server connection, I specified a UID and PWD that I use in various query tools or applications to query "[SchemaX].[TableX]."

I seemed to have success in creating the Linked Server: A Linked Server node Object by the name of "DB2OurDatabase" was created under the Linked Server node in SSMS and when I expand it, I am able to see the of tables in the database.

When I right mouse click on the [SchemaX].[TableX] table and select

"Script Table as => Select To ==> New Window", a new query window was opened with the text

```
--[DB2OurDatabase].[DataCenterCityName2_DB2OurDatabase].[SchemaX].[TableX] 
contains no columns that can be selected or the current user does not have permissions on that object.
GO
```

I don't understand how I was able to create a Linked Server that can see the table names in the database but yet apparently seem to encounter what appears to be a lack of rights to query the table even tghough I am using same credentials that I have used in Squirell SQL query tool, for example, to query the table.

In SSMS, I tried to execute this

```
SELECT * 
FROM [DB2OurDatabase].[DataCenterCityName2_DB2OurDatabase].[SchemaX].[TableX]
```

Error:

> Msg 7314, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The OLE DB provider "IBMDADB2" for linked server "DB2OurDatabase]" does not contain the table ""DataCenterCityName2_DB2OurDatabase"."SchemaX"."TableX"". The table either does not exist or the current user does not have permissions on that table.

I was a little surprised that the fully qualified table name included [DataCenterCityName2_DB2OurDatabase] since I did not specify this when I set up the Linked Server connection, but the name of the DataCenter city was correct so I took this as a further sign that the Linked Server connection was successful.

Nevertheless, I also tried to execute remove this level of the fully qualified table name:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [DB2OurDatabase].[SchemaX].[TableX]
```

which resulted in this error.

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid object name 'DB2OurDatabase.[SchemaX].[TableX]'.

What do I need to do to create a DB2 Linked Server that lets me query the tables in the DB2 database? Here's my linked server properties:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't investigate what are probably multiple ways to conenct and query DB2 from Sql Server, but this worked:

SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(DB2OurDatabase, 'SELECT * FROM SchemaX.TableX')

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you modified the actual commands by replacing object names, so it's impossible to be sure, but the problem may be caused by your use of quoted identifiers (those square brackets), which essentially makes the object names case-sensitive. DB2 will by default create object (table, schema) names in uppercase, unless they are quoted. `create table MySchema.MyTable...` (unquoted) on the DB2 side will create the table `MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE`, and referencing it later from SSMS as `[MySchema].[MyTable]` (using quoted identifiers) will obviously fail.

Comment: I removed the brackets and tried again and got the same error. Thx anyway.

Comment: Does the new error message show object names in upper case or mixed case still?

Answer (score 0):

These are the 3 [steps](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2151/how-to-create-a-sql-server-link-server-to-ibm-db2) that bring me to the solution:

1. Download and install [Microsoft OLE DB Provider for DB2 Version 6.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=100917) (this is the latest version but by the time you read this post there might be a new version now)
2. From the start menu open the Data Access Tool > File > New Data Source and complete all the steps: provide the notorious credentials like Server, Port, Database, User, Password. If unsure contact your DBA. Once completed test the connection and copy the Connection String

[image]

3. Now on SSMS go to Server Object > Linked Servers > New Linked Server and fill up like in picture setting up in the `Provider string` the string you copied before from the Data Access Tool:

[image]

Done, you are good to go now,